# Matlab: define math function g(x) with x+f(x)

Tags: matlab, function, math, inline, nested

I'm trying to define g function in matlab and should be like this `g(x) = x + f(x);`

- x is a number
- f is an inline function

None of the following works:

```
g = x + f(x)
g = inline(x+f);
g = inline(sum(x,f));
```

Comment: Use anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**: You need to Nest an `inline` function inside another function

**Problems with your code**:

1. Enclose items inside the parenthesis of an `inline` function in single quotes
2. Do Not enclose items in parenthesis of an `anonymous` function in single quotes
3. Use `f(x)` when nesting it inside another function to indicate that its a function

**Solution**: You can either Nest an `anonymous` function or an `inline` function inside another `anonymous` or `inline` function, like so:

```
>> f = inline('x.^2') %Or: f = @(x) (x.^2)
>> g = inline('x + f(x)') %Or: g = @(x) (x + f(x))
```

Now,

```
>> g(2.5) 
ans = 8.75
```

Comment: Thanks, this works!
I did something like   
`f1 = inline(handles.tb.functie);
f = @(x) (f1(x));
g = @(x) (x + f(x));`